# Android set date picker min date

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I had a date picker I want to set a min date so that when a user is setting up a date It should not allow bellow that min date and that date should be not less than tomorrow

I had done

```
    //==============Date Picker============================

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch(id){
    case ID_DATEPICKER:

        return new DatePickerDialog(this,myDateSetListener,myYear, myMonth, myDay);
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
    {
        String date = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+"/"+ String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1) +"/"+ String.valueOf(year);
        dateEditText.setText(date);
    } 
};

//==============Date Picker============================
```

Comment: date should be not less than tomorrow ?? do you mean set max date ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [setMinDate (long minDate)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate%28long%29) to set the minimal date supported by this NumberPicker in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 in getDefault() time zone.

If you are using `DatePickerDialog` use `getDatePicker ()` to get `DatePicker`

Comment: +1, didn't notice that method, though the OP still needs a method to limit maximum date supported

Comment: Its also there  setMaxDate see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate(long)

Comment: it's definitely too early in the morning for me to be answering SO questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Set an `OnDateChangedListener` to your `DateTimePicker`, where in

```
onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
```

check if the date is in your allowed range and if not, call `view.updateDate` with maximum or minimum allowed (for example whichever is closest to the entered date).